# Create new user profile account with signInWithGoogle

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-signin

we create a user profile account when a user sign in with his google account  but if we already have a user in our database we don't want to create a new profile account but just to sign in the user.

The problem is when ever we use an existing user the user account details get updated.

I try checking the user account in our database but the code broke.

```
  const signInWithGoogle = () => {
    const id = auth.currentUser.uid;
    const userRef = doc(db, "users", id);

    signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
      .then(async (userCredential) => {
        try {
          const docSnap = await getDoc(userRef);
          if (!docSnap.exists()) {
            await setDoc(doc(db, "users", userCredential.user.uid), {
              username: setUsername(userCredential.user.email),
              profilePic: profilePic,
            });
          }
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }

        toast.success("Sign in successfully");
        navigate("/dashboard");
      })
```

Comment: "the code broke" is hard to help with. What's the problem? Is there an error message? Did you already debug the code? So: If you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: It throw error message : uid is not defined. I set breakpoint and run the code in debugger as U suggested and find the problem Thank Frank

Comment: Good to hear you found the problem @A. Lawal 